# How to import firebase-functions and firebase-admin in ES6 syntax for transpiling with Babel for Node 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm currently writing my cloud functions in ES6 and transpiling with Babel to target the Node v10 environment. And I've noticed something weird.

Why is that when I import `firebase-functions` like this:

`import functions from 'firebase-functions';`

I get this error:

```
!  TypeError: Cannot read property 'https' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\myProject\functions\index.js:28:55)
```

And to fix it, I need to import it like this:

`import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';`

While the following `import` works just fine for the `firebase-admin`:

`import admin from 'firebase-admin';`

**QUESTION**

In short terms, the question is:

Why is that:

```
import functions from 'firebase-functions';            // DOESN'T WORK
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';       // WORKS
import admin from 'firebase-admin';                    // WORKS
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why `import functions from 'firebase-functions';` will not work is because `'firebase-functions'` does not have a "*functions*" default export.

Hence, this error:

```
!  TypeError: Cannot read property 'https' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\myProject\functions\index.js:28:55)
```

---

### Solution:

The first option would be to import an entire module's contents and add `functions` into the current scope containing all the exports from the module `firebase-functions`.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
```

The second option would be to import a single export from a module, `https` in this case, since you are trying to read property `https` of `'firebase-functions'`.

```
import { https } from 'firebase-functions'
```

---

More information can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

Hope this clarifies your question.