# Firebase functions: Can not read property https of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

During `firebase deploy` in terminal, I get an error on this line:

```
// index.js in the output folder
const firebase_functions_1 = __importDefault(require("firebase-functions"));

exports.buyUsedServer = firebase_functions_1.default.https.onRequest(express);

// index.ts in the source folder
import firebaseFunctions from 'firebase-functions';

export const buyUsedServer = firebaseFunctions.https.onRequest(express);
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

What is firebaseFunctions (or the default object) causing an issue here?

This is the full stack trace:

```
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'https' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/owner/PhpstormProjects/shopify/project/functions/outDir/index.js:170:54)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at /home/owner/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:15:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/owner/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:53:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following:

First import the module `firebase-functions`

```
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and setup triggers.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

Then you can call `onRequest()`:

```
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```

You can check the documentation [here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)

Comment: Using the `require` and `exports.` syntax worked, though I'm not sure why import/export failed even after compliation. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

TLDR: all I did was change:

```
import functions from 'firebase-functions'
```

To:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions`
```

Explanation: I was using

```
import functions from 'firebase-functions'
```

After transpiling from TS to JS, my JS file look like this:

```
const firebase_functions_1 = __importDefault(require("firebase-functions"));
```

JS is trying to import the **default** module exported from **firebase-functions**. Problem is, when I looked into **node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v1/index.d.ts** (this could change in the future), it does not have any default export, therefore my JS code is importing **undefined**:

```
// node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v1/index.d.ts
import * as logger from "../logger";
import * as analytics from "./providers/analytics";
import * as auth from "./providers/auth";
import * as database from "./providers/database";
import * as firestore from "./providers/firestore";
import * as https from "./providers/https";
import * as pubsub from "./providers/pubsub";
import * as remoteConfig from "./providers/remoteConfig";
import * as storage from "./providers/storage";
import * as tasks from "./providers/tasks";
import * as testLab from "./providers/testLab";
import { setApp as setEmulatedAdminApp } from "../common/app";
export { analytics, auth, database, firestore, https, pubsub, remoteConfig, storage, tasks, testLab, logger, };
export declare const app: {
    setEmulatedAdminApp: typeof setEmulatedAdminApp;
};
export * from "./cloud-functions";
export * from "./config";
export * from "./function-builder";
export * from "./function-configuration";
```

All I did was change:

```
import functions from 'firebase-functions'
```

To:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions`
```

or just import the **https** module:

```
import { https } from 'firebase-functions'

const helloWorld = https.onCall(...)
```

And you are good to go. Took me a while.

Answer (score 2):

Like you, I wanted to use this ES6 import instead of CommonJS (`require()`). You can resolve this by using

```js
import { https } from 'firebase-functions';
```

I got that answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58817431/how-to-import-firebase-functions-and-firebase-admin-in-es6-syntax-for-transpilin) which has a lot more information.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I faced same issue but not with firebase, instead with influx client. Using a named import like above solved the issue with the "default" object being undefined after transpilation.