# TypeError: Cannot read property 'https' of undefined

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt app built with firebase and vue. Everytime I run my emulator, it would not proceed because of this error: `TypeError: Cannot Find Property 'https' of undefined.` I am having problems with my `https` in my index.ts file. It says that they cannot find this property.
I already imported everything from firebase-functions but it still doesnt work.

This was added in the first line:
`const { functions } = require("firebase-functions");`

I also have this line of code:
`exports.nuxtssr = functions.https.onRequest(app);`

I found some solutions in Stack Overflow and tried these solutions, but it still would not work:
[How to import firebase-functions and firebase-admin in ES6 syntax for transpiling with Babel for Node 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58817431/how-to-import-firebase-functions-and-firebase-admin-in-es6-syntax-for-transpilin)

Answer (score 0):

Your require statement is wrong (you've mixed the import syntax with require):

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I changed it and it still generates the same error.

Comment: then check whether you have the package installed by running npm install and use breakpoints to see what you get in the functions object

Comment: Thank you for responding! I checked my `package.json` file and `firebase-functions` is successfully installed. But I still have the error. Are there other packages needed to be installed?

Comment: I am not sure how you’ve installed the package, try uninstalling and installing again, also do a console.log and see what’s in the functions object when it’s required

Answer (score 0):

I managed to check my files and finally fixed my error. I have a lib folder that stores the transpiled ts to js. And I just fixed it there. IT turned out that the functions object was not read in js.